# How to Solve Framework Error during application build in visual studio?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build an ios Xamarin application from visual studio and i have been getting different errors, managed to supress most of them but this one seems to persist no matter what i do,

little background i am creating this xamarin application on the windows side copying it to virtual mac and deploying it to remote device because i don't have a developers account to do it from windows side

the error is like this:

***Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Cache/...../Framework/RuntimeCore.framework:0xe800801c(No code Signature Found)***

I would like to know what this error is and how i  might rectify it if possible i have tried searching online restarting the machine but none of them worked

Comment: this makes absolutely no sense - "creating an xcode project and copying the bundle identifier to visual studio in virtual mac"

Comment: sorry i misread an article and included this let me edit it

Comment: tbh i thought creating a xcode blank project and copying the bundle identifier and pasting it into info.plist will help with profile provisioning

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check **Free provisioning**

It allows Xamarin.iOS developers to deploy and test their apps on iOS devices without being part of the Apple Developer Program. While simulator testing is valuable and convenient, it is also essential to test apps on physical iOS devices to verify that they function properly under real-world memory, storage, and network connectivity constraints.

Here is related documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos